# Under what circumstanses will AppDomain.DoCallback() fail?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, .net-assembly

I'm trying to use `AppDomain` to load and unload assemblies run-time. I'm trying to get the example on MSDN working in my application before implementing assembly loading, but I'm running into issues - the `DoCallback`-invokation fails with exception

> Could not load file or assembly '[MyPluginAssembly], Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

My assembly (`[MyPluginAssembly]`) is running loaded by a host application (i.e. it is a plugin). The plugins `AppDomain` seem to be the application-domain (i.e. it is not sandboxed in a separate domain). I've tried loading the entry/calling/executing-assembly in the new domain to ensure `[MyPluginAssembly]` is loaded, but even though these calls return non-null I still get the exception above.

The code I use (as in the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.docallback.aspx) + the code to load the "parent"-assemblies):

```
public class PingPong : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private string greetings = "PING!";

    public static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain otherDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("otherDomain");
        // All of these Load()-calls returns non-null
        Assembly entryAssembly = otherDomain.Load(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName());
        Assembly callingAssembly = otherDomain.Load(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName());
        Assembly executingAssembly = otherDomain.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName());

        PingPong pp = new PingPong();
        pp.MyCallBack();
        pp.greetings = "PONG!";
        otherDomain.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(pp.MyCallBack));

        // Output: 
        //   PING! from defaultDomain 
        //   PONG! from defaultDomain
    }

    // Callback will always execute within defaultDomain due to inheritance from 
    // MarshalByRefObject 
    public void MyCallBack()
    {
        string name = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
        if (name == AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationName)
        {
            name = "defaultDomain";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(greetings + " from " + name);
    }
}
```

What circumstances can cause the exception I get?

Comment: Which line gives the exception?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: `otherDomain.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(pp.MyCallBack));`

Comment: Use fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h7t2a2.aspx) method. It is the one to use for sandboxed add-in scenarios like yours. System.AddIn (MAF) is using this method to load the add-in pipeline segments.